# In python my if statement in my while true loop keeps outputting the same "invalid input" text until the program eventually crashes for my text game

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, infinite-loop

```
print(" You can see a faint outline of a coast in the distance... you can either: 1. paddle to the island on the raft ; 2. swim to the island")
    option2 = input("> ")
    while True:
        if (option2 == "1"):
            print("The raft fully sinks... you are left in the freezing cold water. You spent all your     energy trying to keep the raft afloat. You have made your demise inevitable")
            break
        elif (option2 == "2"):
            print("You jump headfirst into the cold water...  not really a good idea, but you seem to have insane swimming skills. Are you Michael Phelps? Anyways you make it to the shore seconds before fainting")
        else:
            print(" Invalid input: Please select one of the options above") <---- It keeps printing this
            continue
```

This is the code that I used. I'm new to Python and I really don't know how while loops function

I 've tried finding syntax issues but I can't spot any

Comment: You are not asking for a new input _inside_ the loop, so it just keeps on looping over the same string. You wrote it that way, so that's what it does; if you want it to do something different, change it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response

Comment: Either this is a simple oversight or a fundamental misunderstanding of how evaluation and assignment in Python works. `option2` is not replaced by `input("> ")` everywhere but by its *result*.

Answer (score 0):

Now it gets looping infinitely if you enter an option that is not "1". You will get into the else statement, which contains the 'continue' keyword.

'continue' means to start the next iteration. And as far as your option is captured only once (before the loop), its never gets changed, so you will be falling into the else block always.

In order to make it work, you need to move your "option2 = input("> ")" inside of the loop and add a break for the second elif:

```
print("You can see a faint outline of a coast in the distance... you can either:\n1. paddle to the island on the raft;\n2. swim to the island;")

while True:
    option2 = input("> ")
    if option2 == "1":
        print("The raft fully sinks... you are left in the freezing cold water. You spent all your energy trying to keep the raft afloat. You have made your demise inevitable")
        break
    elif option2 == "2":
        print("You jump headfirst into the cold water... not really a good idea, but you seem to have insane swimming skills. Are you Michael Phelps? Anyways, you make it to the shore seconds before fainting")
        break
    else:
        print("Invalid input: Please select one of the options above")
```

You can read more about how the while loops work [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_while_loops.asp)

Comment: OP probably hold back on the storm of comments; we generally refrain from thank-you comments (upvote something if you think it's helpful, once you have enough rep) and probably limit your use of comments for asking for clarifications or etc until you are more familiar with the site.

Answer (score -2):

You are getting this error because the while loop doesn't consist exit condition for the elif and else condition of the while loop. You will not face this issue for option 1 as it has a break condition which will help to exit the program from the while loop. Moreover, as you are using an infinite while loop I'm assuming you need input after each print to keep the iteration alive. So, You need to add an exit condition in the if-else scope and also an input for new data after the if-else scope. Below is the correct code added:

```
print(" You can see a faint outline of a coast in the distance... you can either: 1. paddle to the island on the raft ; 2. swim to the island; 3.Exit") 
option2 = input("> ") 
while True: 
    if (option2 == "1"): 
        print("The raft fully sinks... you are left in the freezing cold water. You spent all your energy trying to keep the raft afloat. You have made your demise inevitable")
    elif (option2 == "2"): 
        print("You jump headfirst into the cold water... not really a good idea, but you seem to have insane swimming skills. Are you Michael Phelps? Anyways you make it to the shore seconds before fainting")
    elif (option2 == "3"):
        break
    else: 
        print(" Invalid input: Please select one of the options above")
    option2 = input(">")
```

The above code will help you to take inputs during infinite iteration. Also, I have added one condition that if you input "3" , the loop will be terminated.

Comment: But then why have a loop at all if you `break` it after one iteration unconditionally?

Comment: The question was not clear. If, he wants to make something like a switch case then he need to have input again after the if-else and need to remove the break condition.

Comment: I agree that it could be clearer, but again, what do you think is the point of `while True:` if you `break` in the middle of the first iteration? (Also, you could refactor to a single `break` after the entire `if` tree.) A much simpler and more obvious solution is to remove `while True:` if you don't want it to loop, ever.

Comment: @tripleee, As he said he is a newbie so I thought he just wants to play around with loop and if-else. Anyway, i have updated my answer with a correct code snippet. Thanks for the correction

Comment: It's slightly better but not good enough to deserve an upvote IMHO; and now, the text doesn't agree with the code. The code duplication is unattractive; but then the obvious fix would turn this into a duplicate of the other answer. Anyway, simple beginner questions like this should probably be closed as duplicates instead of answered individually.

Comment: (Separately, probably don't ask for upvotes in comments; the effect tends to be the opposite of what you hoped for.)

Comment: @tripleee, Thanks, I'm new so I didn't know that. Anyways, I have updated the whole code with exit condition too. Hopefully, this will look good.